# Correlation and Maximal Information Coefficient values interpretation

Tags: correlation

In the recent research I had to explain few low values appearing from the correlation calculation, so I went for Maximal Information Coefficient (MIC) to see if there is a possibility of having non-linear relation between the variables which were reporting values close to 0 when calculating correlation. When I added new code in R and re-ran the analysis I could observe that MIC was reporting similar values. Having similar values reported by both methods can I conclude that relation between the variables where the values are similar is linear?

(I am not coming from Math background, hope I am asking something which makes sense :D)

Answer (score 0):

when the pearson value is zero it means that there is no linear relationship between data. When MIC is zero it implies statistically independent variables and there is neither linear nor nonlinear relationship.